# How can I set a default value in array i want to set my subject default

Tags: php, forms

How can I set a default value in array i want to set my subject default
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/etrsY.png)

**Here is my Code**

```
public function sendEmail(Request $request)
    {
      
              $data = array(
                'name'      =>  $request->name,
                'phone'  =>  $request->phone,
                **'subject' ="New Client",**
                'email'      =>  $request->email
              );

           Mail::to('info@example.com')->send(new ContactMail($data));
           return redirect()->route('home');
    }
```

Comment: `=` should be `=>`. Otherwise that's how to do it.

Comment: Do you mean that you have $request->subject and you want to $data['subject'] value was 'New Client' when $request->subject is null?

Comment: `'subject' => $request->subject ?? "New Client",`

Comment: yes i want to set the subject value from controller as new client

Comment: i want to redirect to home page after form submission            return redirect()->route('home');   its not working for me

Comment: any suggestion??

Answer (score 0):

Here Is the Answer by [Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar)
'subject' => $request->subject ?? "New Client",